# If I buy an exclusive OEM app, can I download it in a future phone of another brand?

Tags: apps, store

Some Games/App are available only for one OEM. Let's take Nokia for example.

1. I buy a game called RISK (exclusive to Nokia) in my Nokia Lumia 800.
2. Several months later, I buy another phone. For example, the HTC Windows Phone 8X.

In Windows Phone, app purchases are associated with your Microsoft account, so you can transfer them to a new phone. Does this apply to OEM-exclusive apps as well, even if the new phone was made by a different OEM?

Answer (score 2):

Apps that are specific to an OEM or carrier are only available when using the relevant device or carrier (as appropriate).

Theses show up in your [list of purchased apps](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/my/purchase-history) with a note:

> This app is not available for all phones. Try downloading it on your phone.

If you've changed to use a different phone/carrier from when you purchased it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. OEM apps are every manufacturers way to carry out marketing for their products, altough the port would be a piece of cake because i don't think you need to write out new specific drivers for a game(as an example).

Comment: I have NOT down-voted this answer, but I was tempted to because (i) You haven't listed a source for your answer of 'no', a source might not be possible for this, but it would be useful. (ii) Since the hardware has to meet certain requirements there isn't really a need to port WP apps and the exclusive ones are just exclusive because they have paid to be so--you would only ever need to backport WP8 apps e.g. a WP8 Direct-X game to a WP7 XNA Game.

Comment: its a logical thing, dont you think? if i would list a source that pigs fly would you believe me? I say its not so hard to take a general look at things and get to a conclusion, but if you rely only on "sources", then my best wishes. As a second argument, nokia drive and city lens work on the lumia 610 and only has 256 of RAM, so you cant tell me that its a hardware constraint, can you? LOL

Comment: Yeah I said it might not be possible, but I wouldn't rule out an official page from Microsoft/Nokia stating that apps downloaded from an OEM marketplace are different from the official marketplace or a page stating that you can re-download your timed exclusive app when the exclusivity period expires. For the hardware, I was thinking of something more specialised than RAM and specific to a single OEM e.g. new CPU/GPU architecture, sensor, dual screens, something that you see happening on Android.

Comment: yes, thats why the .NET Framework is used so its machine-invariant. And most people use .NET to develop the apps, so the hardware is not an issue from a Windows phone developers point of view.